# Check radio button if another radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

New to the angular js need to know how to check radio button 'B' if Radio button 'A' is checked?

My code

```
<input type="radio" name ="employeeData.seatChange1" ng-model="employeeData.seatChange" value="yes" > A
<input type="radio" name ="employeeData.seatChange" ng-model="employeeData.seatChange" value="no" > B 
<input type="radio" name ="employeeData.seatChange3" ng-model="employeeData.seatChange" value="no1" > C
```

Comment: You can't check both of them if the have the same name. That's what a radio button does.

Comment: Better use checkboxes for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

you'll want to have multiple radio buttons, each with it's own value to set some property to (although this is weird for a yes no you are better off with a checkbox, but if you had multiple values this is how radio buttons work)

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="employeeData.seatChange" ng-value="true" />A
<input type="radio" ng-model="employeeData.seatChange" ng-value="true" />B
```

when you have just one radio button, if it is not checked by default or you have no ng-value it will be undefined, but also having only one radio button, you could never unselect it.

Try this, Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check both radio button ,rather than using radio button go for check box ,as I don't know why you are using radio button its better to use check box radio button.

If you want to use Radio button only then in the Don't use name as if name is used both radio button is grouped so one is checked then automatically other also unchecked which is default.So as VikrantMore says you can avoid name.

My advice as per requirement go for check box.